# I want to update table emp_appointment with data from other table data

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables named  `emp_appointment` and `employees`. `Employees` have  2 column named `EMPLOYEE_ID1` and `SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX` and table `emp_appointment` have also 2 column named `dep_id` and `EMPLOYEE_ID1` I want to update table `emp_appointment` column `dep_id` with data of `employees` table from column  `SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX` both have same id's so I write this code but not worked

```
DECLARE  
   EMP_id EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID1%TYPE;  
   SUBSID_ID EMPLOYEES.SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX%TYPE;
 
   CURSOR C_EMP is  
      SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID1, SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX =  EMPLOYEE_ID1 ;  
BEGIN  
   OPEN C_EMP;  
   LOOP  
      FETCH C_EMP into EMP_id,SUBSID_ID ;
      UPDATE EMP_APPOINTMENT
  SET DEP_ID = SUBSID_ID
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID1= SUBSID_ID; 
      EXIT WHEN C_EMP%notfound;      
      
END LOOP;  
CLOSE C_EMP;  
END;
```

help needed from Masters Please

Comment: If you have some code that doesn't work, it is very helpful to tell us what, specifically you are seeing.  Are you getting an error?  If so, what error?  Is it a compilation error or a runtime error?  What line number?  What is the error stack?  Or is it not doing something you expect?  If so, show us what isn't working.  Something like "There is a row of data in table A that looks like this, there is a row of data in table B that looks like that.  I run this code and I expect B to be updated to look like this but it actually looks like that" with what data.

Comment: @JustinCave Respected It didn't give me any error nor any thing just procedure complete message so what I have detail I passed thanks for your concerns

Comment: That's useful information that you should include.  That at least confirms that your code compiles and runs.  And then someone can look and notice that your `where` clause is comparing `employee_id` to `subsid_id` rather than, presumably, `emp_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you should **not do this**, unless dep_id id necessary as part of a foreign key. What you are doing is just copying data, which is just a bad idea. It exposes you to data inconsistency, what happens when dep_id contains a value that does not exist in employees. Instead you should just Join the tables and select subsid_account_idx from employees.  But if you insistant then just use a single update.

```
update emp_appointment  ea 
    set dep_id = (select subsid_account_idx 
                    from employees e 
                   where e.employee_id1 = ea.employee_id1
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and code worked for me thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
MERGE INTO emp_appointment e
    USING employees. Employees h
    ON (h.EMPLOYEE_ID1= e.SUBSID_ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET e.DEP_ID = h.SUBSID_ACCOUNT_IDX ;
```

and this merge into syntax:

```
MERGE INTO table1
  USING table_reference h
  ON (conditions)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET table1.column1 = h.value1, table1.column2 = h.value2
```